# Android socket client not receiving from java server

Tags: android, sockets

My app is sending data to the java socket server but it is only displaying the first message it receives from the server and not the other messages.

1. The Server is multi threaded.
2. I have created two clients in java both are sending and receiving messages through the server but in android app I am having problem receiving data.

This is the complete code of the Android client.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
Socket client;
EditText writeMsg;
TextView displayMsg;
String userInput;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    writeMsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    displayMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);


    ReceiveMsg obj = new ReceiveMsg();
    Thread tr = new Thread(obj);
    tr.start();
}


// A button to send msg to server when clicked

public void sendBtn(View view){

    userInput = writeMsg.getText().toString();
    SendMessage object = new SendMessage();
    object.execute();
```

}

```
private class SendMessage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {

            client = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 4444);
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            output.print(userInput);
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            client.close();

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;

    }
}

class ReceiveMsg implements Runnable {
    public void run() {


            try {
               client = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 4444);

                  BufferedReader in =
                        new BufferedReader(
                                new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                int i = 0;

                while (i == 0) {

                   displayMsg.setText(in.readLine());
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

        }

    }
```

}

I want the app to display the newly received message in the text-view and overwrite the existing message.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You create two client sockets. One for sending and one for receiving.

Normal would be only one client socket who sends a command and then receives the reply of the server.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, you are reading lines, but you aren't sending lines.

Use `println()`, not `print()`.

You also need to stop reading when you get an `IOException`, or when `readLine()` returns null.

Why there are two client sockets is another mystery.